# How to create geospatial module with AWS lambda and dynamo db

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

First let me thank you for taking the time in reading my question.

My plan was to add latitude and longitude records on my persons records in dynamodb and then use a geo library, preferably written in nodejs,  for calculating nearby persons in a given radius. So the plan was, for example, return the persons only from this 50 mile radius.

So far, the only geo-libraries i have tried allows me to pass lat and long to it and confirm if it is within the radius given. The problem with this is that I have to loop my whole dynamodb table to get results. Is there a reverse kind of function for this in which I pass a latlong point and radius to the geo library and then the geo library passes me some lat and long boundaries so that I can easily query it to dynamodb(ex. (lat<:latboundary1 AND lat>:latboundary 2) AND (long<:longboundary1 AND long>:longboundary 2)  )

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but why don't you just compute those boundaries by yourself?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. I'm not sure about the formulas I see but if im going to compute it is this correct?[BoundingCoordinates](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates)

Comment: Hey there! Did you figure out a solution to this? i am wondering the same thing haha.

Comment: Hi @LucasSenechal, I think the best solution is geohashing. In dynamodb you cant you cant have 2 GSIs, so you cant query by lat and lng. The problem with geohashing is that  i dont know how create one. I have seen open source libraries for this but it doesnt really show the basic concepts behind it or how to build one from scratch. It just shows you how to install it in a server which beats the purpose of dynamodb + lambda.

TLDR: No

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This nodejs library](https://github.com/davidwood/node-geopoint) provides a function that calculates the bounding box based on a point and a radius. You can use the returned SW and NE points for your query.

> .boundingCoordinates(distance, radius, inKilometers): Calculates the bounding coordinates of distance from the point and returns an array with the SW and NE points of the bounding box . If radius is not provided, the radius of the Earth will be used. The distance is calculated in miles unless inKilometers is true

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It helped. but its not as precise as the render in gmaps. ex:http://beta.doc.sg.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/geo_test.html#

the npm geopoint function returns an array of:
0:[
 _degLat:14.385677399028326
 _degLon:120.98036575219953
 _radLat:0.2510774357427784
 _radLon:2.111505712642868
],
1:[
 _degLat:14.394670600971672
 _degLon:120.98965024780044
 _radLat:0.25123439672698655
 _radLon:2.111667757660491
],
ive only used degLat and degLon of arrays 0 and 1. am i suppose to use radLat and radLon too?

Comment: I did not evaluate the precision, my use case does not require very high precision. Btw, the geopoint library credits mention that the calculation is based on [BoundingCoordinates](http://janmatuschek.de/LatitudeLongitudeBoundingCoordinates). It is a matter of preference if you want to use degrees or radians.